# Table and background img problem

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my site.I cant make the table appears on the img. It appears down of the image or up of the image. I need some help with the codes. Actually i dont want the img to reapet and to fit in users window everytime. The code to insert the img is this

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;" background="bg_body.jpg">
```

And the code that a actually helped me but didnt solved the problem 100% because table didnt appears with img is this

```
<style> <!-- body { margin: 0px; } --> </style>
<img src='whatever' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;' />
```

Comment: can you explain more about the "table"...

Comment: Take a look at my existing site http://www.lineage2explosive.tk/. I want to make this img appears once and not reapeared(fit to window depends users resolution). And the buttons i have +text are made with table. But when i put the codes i post in my question seperates the table from the image and appears the buttons and the text down of it.

Comment: http://l2explosive.ucoz.org/vote.html Check the source code from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a background image to fit the size of the browser (which i'm guessing at, but if you have a 100% height and width on your image, that seems what you're after), you could do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body{height:100%;}
.backgroundlayer { position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1; }
.toplayer { position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:2; }
</style>
```

and then in the body of your code...

```
<body>
    <img src="someimage.png" style="height:100%;width:100%;" class="backgroundlayer" />
    <div class="toplayer">
        my content above the image...it doesn't have to be a div...use a table if you want
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well i am so newbie. I insert the codes you give me and works perfect.
But now vote enter button and text dont appears.It seems like they are behind the img. Probably i didnt insert the codes in the right place.Please take a look at the code i have at this page. I bet you know how to do it. View-->source code www.lineage2explosive.tk

Comment: I presume it is the vote.html page? for me anyway, it still looks like it did when you first posted the web site address...

Comment: My false you check the source code from here http://l2explosive.ucoz.org/vote.html

Comment: I just grabeed your source code, modified it a bit and uploaded it...you've got 1 day to access this file: http://senduit.com/cc6533

Comment: put it in the same place as your vote.html but call it something else to test it out...

Comment: Thanks a lot davidsleeps i dont how to thank you. Problem solved.

Comment: Finally i am trying to put the text and  the other at the center but i cant. I am inserting align middle at the table but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CSS background properties.

HTML (something like this, un-tested):

```
<body ... style="background-image:url('bg_body.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

If you want your background image to "resize" to the browser, you will have to hack it to work. One common way is probably to use two div tags; the first one will contain the image at 100% size, with absolute positioning. The second one contains your actual body content, with a higher z-value. It is a lot more work than you might think.

For detailed discussion on this, see this thread: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/help/ftopic4503.html

Comment: broken link :S i cant proceed

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple things here that don't make too much sense:

"oncontextmenu="return false;" are you trying to run some sort of javascript? If so, you need to call a function before the "return false", like so:

```
<body onload="someFunction() return false;">
```

Also, I don't think you can set a background for an element the way you did it, it would be more like this:

```
<table style="background:path/to/my/image/...">
```

I'd love to help some more, but please explain yourself a little better.

ok, I'd suggest you do something like this:

Whether it is on an external style sheet, or embedded inside the head tags, you can set the image size with some simple CSS, like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-image:url(../path/to/image);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Try this to see if it works, I'll help you more if it doesn't.

Comment: Take a look at my existing site lineage2explosive.tk. I want to make this img appears once and not reapeared(fit to window depends users resolution). And the buttons i have +text are made with table. But when i put the codes i post in my question seperates the table from the image and appears the buttons and the text down of it.

Comment: the return false; statement is correct...it just cancels the context menu, so it's not meant to run any further functions

Comment: this works with table and image and image dont reapeted but it doesnt works with fit on browser. Understand what i mean?